azure static webapp redirect subdomain to internal path
I am running an angular app with Azure static web app. Is there a way to redirect subdomain to an internal path.
Let's say :  abc.mydomain.com. to mydomain.com/abc
I have already configured CNAME in my DNS.
I have tried configuring a .htaccess file. ( and web.config. even I know server is ubuntu).
None of them working.
Tried also configuring staticwebapp.config.json but it seems to be working for internal route not subdomain.
Thanks in advance

You can add the redirect route in your code directly and edit your staticwebapp.config.json like below:-
app-routing.module.ts
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component'; 
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'abc', component: AbcComponent },

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }

staticwebapp.config.json
{
  "routes": [
    {
      "route": "/abc/*",
      "rewrite": "/index.html"
    }
  ]
}

If you do not have route add the code directly to your app.component.ts:-
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <div>
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) {
    this.route.url.subscribe(url => {
      const path = url[0].path;
      if (path === 'abc') {
        window.location.href = 'https://customdomain.com/abc';
      }
    });
  }
}



For me working overwriting ngOnInit().

Okay, great....

Seems the only solution is doing it inside angular.
In app.component.ts:
ngOnInit(): void {

var link = window.location.hostname
var subdomain = link.split(".")[0]


if(subdomain == link.split(".")[1]){/*do nothing*/}
else if(subdomain != ''){
  this.router.navigate([subdomain]);
}}

